# Image Recognition Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to distinguish different types of beers in my fridge using a Raspberry Pi. I saw a [very good tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box?view=all) on Adafruit that utilized OpenCV for face recognition. Can these same face recognition algorithms, Eigenfaces & Fisherfaces, be used to train my raspberry pi for recognizing different types of beer cans?

Comment: Don't they have barcodes?

Comment: They do, but beer cans vary much more in colors (or at least mine do), which leads me to believe that image recognition would be simpler than fiddling with a barcode scanner

Answer (score 2):

Not being an expert, I would guess that face recognition algorithms are way to specialized and heavy to do this. They will try to identify a "face" first of all - two eyes and a nose and a mouth and so on - and then try to identify them based on a set of parameters that can be detected in that face.

I think you would be a lot better off using some kind of optical character recognition (OCR) software, or simply sample the colour and draw wild conclusions from there.

Answer (score 2):

Since the RPi now comes with Mathematica, we can use its image processing functionality to analyze beer labels.  The folks at Mathematica.SE have [performed a similar task](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5676/7167) with Jelly jars (apparently Mathematica users are teatotalers).

I have not tried the operations above on an RPi; however assuming there are no problems with limited memory or excessive image processing time, using an RPi with this process is in principle the same.